# Error when trying to programmatically change values in Application.Current.Resources

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am getting the following error when I try to change any value in **Application.Current.Resources**

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'No installed components were detected.
>
> Local values are not allowed in resource dictionary with Source set [Line: 0 Position: 0]'*

I have attempted to change both system defined values as well as custom defined ones, but I am getting the same error.

```
Application.Current.Resources["ListViewItemBackgroundSelected"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.FirstOrDefault()["AccentColor"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
```

On multiple docs over the web I have seen that the above two are valid ways of setting the resource values, bot for some reason they are not working for me.

BasicPageResources.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:iDownloadManager.UIResources"
    xmlns:UI="using:iDownloadManager.UIpages">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColor" Color="Red"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

App.xaml

```
<Application
    x:Class="iDownloadManager.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:iDownloadManager">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary >
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="UIResources\BasicPageResources.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
    
</Application>
```

Comment: This doesn't look like the problem with assigning a new value. I would check if `ResourceDictionary` and `MergedDictionaries` declarations are ok.

Comment: Please post the contents of your Application's merged dictionaries

Comment: I have edited the question with the code for ResourceDictionary and MergedDictionaries.

Comment: And can you reproduce the problem with this exact code? Check if you have a [mcve]

Comment: I saw you asked the same thread in MSDN. Since I could not reproduce your issue, could you please provide the test environment? Could you please upload a [mcve] as Henk mentioned?